# How to use a list to supply argruments to sprintf in r

Tags: r, string, printf, function-parameter

I'm trying to automate some code that populates some generic text that I have. For example, I might have two strings that have different number of placeholders in them for numbers. The way the code is currently set up it requires passing the number of values that the string will have to add to it. If I could unpack a list somehow so it provides that `...` in sprintf then I can skip all the ugly `if` statements.

Thanks in guys!

```
text_1 <- "This is a number %.1f"
text_2 <- "This is a number %.1f and this %.1f"

v1 <- 0.1
v2 <- 0.5
type = 1

if(type == 1)sprintf(text_1, v1)
if(type == 2)sprintf(text_2, v1, v2)

# ideally
l <- list(v1, v2)
sprint(text_2, unlist(l)) # something like unlist.
```

Comment: How about this? `do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = text_2, l))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(l, sprintf, fmt = text_2)
#[1] "This is a number 0.1 and this 0.5"
```

---

Can be wrapped in a function

```
f1 <- function(params, txt){
      reduce(params, sprintf, fmt = txt)
  }

f1(l, text_1)
#[1] "This is a number 0.1"

f1(l, text_2)
#[1] "This is a number 0.1 and this 0.5"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank very much (and escpically for the speady reply!)